# New navigation bar showing newest question notification even when the new question is not in filter criteria

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, new-nav

I have filtered for android and webp tag on all condition.
This means the question must have both tags to appear in results.

But when any new quesiton posted its showing notification that 1 new question with this activity even when the question doesn't fit in the filter crieteria

[image]

**The new question doesn't have the webp tag.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in build `#3919` (meta.stackoverflow.com) and build `#3024` (stackoverflow.com).