# What happened to my tabbed bar

Tags: discussion

I've opted into the new design for stackoverflow.  It was great and I loved it.  Today, I woke up and navigated to stack overflow and my tabbed bar for favorite tags dissapeared.

I was using a layout similar to what is posted in this question
[New navigation bar showing newest question notification even when the new question is not in filter criteria](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308985/new-navigation-bar-showing-newest-question-notification-even-when-the-new-questi)

Can anyone tell me how I can get my Tag's Tabbed bar back?